# How do I find out what collations are available in SQL 2000/2005

Tags: sql, collation

If I need to choose a collation mode to work with, how do I know what collations are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct COLLATION_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS order by 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this query to list the available collation modes:

SELECT *
FROM fn_helpcollations()